# Reading in data for a Quine-McKluskey program

Tags: c++

Hello everyone I am doing a program for the Quine-McKluskey method of minimizing boolean expressions and I am having massive problems reading in and storing the data from a file.

Example of input data: 
Abc aBC AbC aBC X 
ABCD abcd ABcd aBcD X
S 
ABCD .....

lower case represents a "not"
The terms are separated by a blank
X represents the end of the expression
and S represents the end of the file

Currently I am trying to read in each character one by one and put it into an Char array ( should I be reading them into a char array or an array of strings for the expressions?)

Let me know what else I need to post, any and all help is very much appreciated i've been working on this for about a month now when time allows it and have not been able to get very far

Comment: Please post some relevant code, and a description of the actual problem...

Comment: What is the QM method going to do with input data? What type of operations are needed to achieve your desired result? It would be helpful if you could elaborate a little bit more.

Comment: You can find a complete implementation of QM (and MCDC) in https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/MCDC . Maybe this will give you some hints.